# What would cause one tool chest drawer to fail to lock?

Tags: lock, storage

I have a Harborfreight U.S. General upper tool chest (part #64440) that is only a year old. The upper right drawer fails to lock. The remaining ones do. No tools are blocking anything as the drawer is now empty. Removed the drawer and did not see anything unusual. I checked the back end of the drawer and it appeared ok...nothing smashed in. No interference from drawer below it.

Before I dismantle the entire thing, I am wondering if anyone who owns this same unit has seen this problem and what causes it? Is something missing on a drawer slide? I kinda suspect foulplay, but won't conclude that until I remove all the drawers....FWIW, the 90-degree tubular lock works, just not on this one drawer.

My pictures are apparently too big to post here....

Could this open drawer allow someone to access the rest of the (locked) drawers and contents?

Comment: To add pictures, click "Edit" and then click on the "mountain & sun" icon. Your pictures need to be either accessible from your computer (able to find the file) or via a URL. They will be saved in imgur but automatically in a special StackExchange (no charge or separate imgur signup needed).

Comment: you can also just paste them in.

Comment: It's from harbor freight. You're lucky any of the drawers lock, for whatever level of security a harbor freight "lock" provides...

Comment: Haha. The locks are by Admiral, I think. But the locks work....just not in this one drawer. And you are providing an opinion and, although I agree with it, does not advance my question to an answer. I thought opinions weren't allowed...

Comment: Do you have a 2 year old?